# How to zoom out tasks in Microsoft Project 2010?

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2010

Zooming in/out changes timescale for Gantt chart, but is there a way to zoom in/out the tasks area?
Having many columns I don't want to scroll left/right each time I want to get to a piece of information, I just want to zoom out so that I can view them all, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry.  You might consider creating multiple tables (lists of fields) and switching tables instead of trying to make one table to show everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents on this subject. It is a real pain not to have the proper zoom capability for WBS area. No matter how much research I did, apparently Microsoft forgot to take care of this feature if PM needs to deal with multiple columns which I do all the time.

So to survive this is what I did - something very simple: for the duration of the editing I took columns that I don't need at the moment and significantly reduce the width of them so fit everything on the screen and to avoid the horizontal scrolling.

After I editing is complete I restore column to the needed width. Not perfect, but works!